# Create a zip archive from a directory using PHP

Tags: php, zip, php-ziparchive

I have under my PHP file directory a folder named `details`. In it I have 2 folders. One named `zip` and the other one named by the user input, which stored in `$id`.

Under `$id` folder, I have a lot of folders. I want to compress everything under `$id` folder into a zip archive stored in `zip` folder, and to be named `$id.zip`.

I saw about 5-6 solutions on Stack Overflow to this problem, but none of them worked. At the end the `zip` folder stayed empty. This is mostly the code everyone used in their solutions:

```
$zipname = 'adcs.zip';
$zip = new ZipArchive;
$zip->open($zipname, ZipArchive::CREATE);
if ($handle = opendir('.')) {
  while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {
    if ($entry != "." && $entry != ".." && !strstr($entry,'.php')) {
        $zip->addFile($entry);
    }
  }
  closedir($handle);
}

$zip->close();
```

This solution didn't work for me. I copied it from one of the questions so `adcs.zip` isn't my real zip archive name.

I need a solution that works, and is adjusted to use `$id` as part of the directory to compress.

How can I do that?

Comment: I think you should explain why the code that's valid for everybody is not appropriate for you, so we know what needs to be changed.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález sometimes lib-zib does not compiled with php , so i think he have to install it

Comment: `ini_set('display_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL);` put this line at top of your script to check what's going wrong

Comment: @hassan If he wants a pure PHP solution that doesn't need the Zip extension he would just be asking that, I presume.

Comment: i know, i'm talking about `ZipArchive` specially which is part of `libzip`

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález I don't what is wrong with my code. This is why I'm asking for help or maybe another method to create the zip archive

Comment: @hassan Currently I'm not using any external library. Should I?

Comment: first check the errors `ini_set('display_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL);`